# Upload file to be bought with paypal

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal

I am using an html form to create a buy now button on a webpage. I would like the buy now button to lead to a paypal page which the user can enter their information. If the information is validated, the user should be able to download the file they requested to buy. The button is working and the price is being set correctly but I am not sure how to upload the file to paypal so it can be downloaded directly once the payment is processed.

Here is the code for the current html form i am using:

```
    <form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" class="paypal">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="$bandEmail">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="$song1Name">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="$song1Price">
        <input type="image" src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
    </form>
```

Comment: you dont upload anything to paypal, after payment customer is retuned to your site where you deliver the file

Comment: how do i choose where the user is redirected to after the payment is complete

Comment: either in the form with (`<input type="hidden" name="return" value="`) or set up auto return in your account

Comment: okay that works, what if i want to have it return to a page that downloads a specific file uploaded in the initial webpage where the purchase was made. Is there a way to send this file so it can be used in the php return page?

Comment: add some id tracking